# Searching for the unique key (not in meta)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, combinations

With which SQL Server standard tool it is possible to search unique key in the table's data (but not in meta declaration)?

P.S. I am thinking to write such script by myself. May be you could point a snippet for 
combinatorics in t-sql? e.g. for generation all Combinations from n by 1..n ?

P.P.S About problem complexity for those who do not see it. It is important that we do not need to analyze the whole data to dismiss the hypnotize that those two columns is the 'unique key'. With real world, 'report-like', sorted data even after analysing first two rows, I think, it is possible to remove many of columns combinations. So I feel such algorithm should have 'before full table compare' phase. But there it is a question for what portion of data to choose for this 'before full table compare' phase . The best candidate about which I think is the 'page'... If data unique in the page we could test the uniqueness on whole table, if not unique (on the page), then go to the next column set.

Comment: The fact, that values in column are unique tells nothing about column uniqness, any row added may contain duplicate value if there is no unique constraint, which AFAIK can be determined only in meta.  Of course you can check if Count(ColumnName) equals Count(distinct ColumnName), but it will only tell wether the values are unique, not that they must be.

Comment: This question is just about data analyzes automation. From this point of view , columns with unique values tells me what I want to find:  columns with unique values. BTW comparing count() and count(distinct ) on whole table seems not the most productive method, first I could compare e.g. values from the first page. And if they are equal - test all table.

Comment: I just want to be clear: do you want to avoid the "system views"? (sys.columns, for instance).  Are you trying to avoid other API approaches (such as SQL DMO)?

Comment: I need to analize data and find the column combinations that works as "unique key". I do not want "avoid system views" just because there are no such inforamtion defined for those tables. Let say it is a heap just loaded from CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.col, count(*)
  from table t1 
  join table t2
    on t1.col = t2.col 
 group by t1.col 
having count(*) > 1
```

if zero rows are returned then it is unique

more than one column

```
select t1.cola, t1.colb, count(*)
  from table t1 
  join table t2
    on t1.cola = t2.cola
   and t1.colb = t2.colb 
 group by t1.cola, t2.colb
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I know it already but thank you. If you could point how to load just one page of data and test it, such information could help me much more. In general case of analyzing  'unknown' report-like data, we can say that two columns could not be a unique key for this table just after analizing first page. Or even after anlysint first two rows. Actually this is dilema what portion of data I need two choose.

Comment: If you know that already then why do you need help testing it.